# onSingleTapConfirmed is never triggered

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, touch-event, gesturedetector

I am trying to implement a click listener for tap and fling, but for some reason the `onSingleTapConfirmed` method is never triggered and I don't really know why.

I have tried this in a different project only with two buttons and I had no issue with implementing it there, but for some reason in this app it does not work even if the code is the same.

**MyGestureDetector.class:**

public class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

```
private MainGame mainGame;

MyGestureDetector(MainGame mainGame) {
    this.mainGame = mainGame;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GESTURE", "OnDOwn detected");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("GESTURE: ", "Single Tap detected");
    mainGame.clickedView();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    try {
        if (e1.getY() < e2.getY()) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "Up to Down swipe: " + e1.getY() + " - " + e2.getY());
            Log.d("Speed", String.valueOf(velocityY) + "pixels/second");
            Objects.requireNonNull(mainGame.getSupportActionBar()).show();
        }

        if (e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {
            Log.d("Gesture", "Down to Up swipe: " + e1.getY() + " - " + e2.getY());
            Log.d("Speed", String.valueOf(velocityY) + "pixels/second");
            Objects.requireNonNull(mainGame.getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d("ActionBar: ", "Nullpoint caught");
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**MainGame.class (snippets):**

```
public class MainGame extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
ConstraintLayout layout;
TextView fullNameP1;
TextView fullNameP2;
TextView gameScoreP1;
TextView gameScoreP2;
View mCurrenView;
private MyGestureDetector = myGestureDetector;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_game);

    initializeLayoutViews();
    initializeLayoutValues();

    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
    layout.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);


    layout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    gameScoreP1.setOnTouchListener(this);        
    gameScoreP2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    fullNameP1.setOnTouchListener(this);
    fullNameP2.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

private void initializeLayoutViews() {
layout = findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);
mainLayout.clone(layout);
fullNameP1 = findViewById(R.id.fullNameP1);
fullNameP2 = findViewById(R.id.fullNameP2);
gameScoreP1 = findViewById(R.id.gameScoreP1);
gameScoreP2 = findViewById(R.id.gameScoreP2);
myGestureDetector = new MyGestureDetector(this);
mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, myGestureDetector);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    mCurrenView = v;
    return this.mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

void clickedView() {
switch(mCurrenView.getId()) {
//perform actions
}
}
}
```

And this is my log anywhere on the screen:

> 2019-02-23 17:51:24.801 7177-7177/package D/GESTURE:
>   OnDOwn detected 2019-02-23 17:51:25.612 7177-7177/package
>   D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected 2019-02-23 17:51:26.190
>   7177-7177/package D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected 2019-02-23
>   17:51:26.718 7177-7177/package D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected
>   2019-02-23 17:51:26.869 7177-7177/package D/Gesture: Down
>   to Up swipe: 275.33337 - -5.333313 2019-02-23 17:51:27.364
>   7177-7177/package D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected 2019-02-23
>   17:51:27.575 7177-7177/package D/Gesture: Up to Down
>   swipe: 466.6667 - 772.3962 2019-02-23 17:51:28.438
>   7177-7177/package D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected 2019-02-23
>   17:51:28.643 7177-7177/package D/Gesture: Down to Up
>   swipe: 215.33337 - -52.07727 2019-02-23 17:51:29.224
>   7177-7177/package D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected 2019-02-23
>   17:51:29.414 7177-7177/package D/Gesture: Up to Down
>   swipe: 8.0 - 272.0 2019-02-23 17:51:30.584
>   7177-7177/package D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected 2019-02-23
>   17:51:35.959 7177-7177/package D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected
>   2019-02-23 17:51:36.356 7177-7177/package D/GESTURE:
>   OnDOwn detected 2019-02-23 17:51:36.737 7177-7177/package
>   D/GESTURE: OnDOwn detected

As you can see, `onSingleTapConfirmed` is never triggered even if all I do is a simple tap when a `OnDown` is not preceded by a swipe.

**EDIT**
Did a few test logging the actions and the problem is that the gesture detector does not see any of my views except `layout` for some reason because `onSingleTapConfirmed` gets triggered outside any of the text views and also if I disable the listener for them.
I would really need help on this, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the other views were not clickable for some reason.

The code works as intended now after adding the following to before adding the listeners:

```
    gameScoreP1.setClickable(true);
    gameScoreP2.setClickable(true);
    fullNameP1.setClickable(true);
    fullNameP2.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the value provided by the `GestureDetector`'s `onTouchEvent`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return this.mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```